# Listen to other process windows

Tags: c#, winapi

We have a third party winforms software that we need to run as a batch
I need to monitor if a certain form for a certain process (we run several processes at the same time) is shown.

I have used this method to get all window handles for a process

```
public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(int processId)
{
    var handles = new List<IntPtr>();
    try
    {

        foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
            Win32.EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id,
                (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    return handles.Select(h => (int)h);
}
```

Then this method to get the window caption from the hwnd

```
public string GetTitle(int hwnd)
{
    int length = Win32.SendMessage((IntPtr)hwnd, Win32.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    Win32.SendMessage((IntPtr)hwnd, Win32.WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Each second I poll the process with above methods, but sometimes it fails to detected a window shown. The window in question is opened more than a second so its not the pol frequency.

Is there a more reliable way of getting callbacks when a window is closed/opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way to listen to window creation and destruction is using a [CBT hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx). Listen for `HCBT_CREATEWND` and `HCBT_DESTROYWND`. This MSDN article, [Windows Hooks in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx), covers the subject from a .net perspective.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, it takes a ThreadId, how can I ensure that its the GUI thread I use?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

maybe that can help

[1] http://spradip.wordpress.com/category/programming-c/page/2/

and this any ms C++ example

[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx